# Source other scripts in Linux startup script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I came across the following scripts and there is something that I cannot fully understand

```
    #!/bin/sh /etc/rc.common
# Copyright (C) 2006-2011 OpenWrt.org

START=50

start() {
        mkdir -m 0755 -p /var/run/vsftpd
        service_start /usr/sbin/vsftpd
}

stop() {
        service_stop /usr/sbin/vsftpd
}
```

How is '/etc/rc.common' used here?

here is the contents of rc.common

```
#!/bin/sh
# Copyright (C) 2006-2011 OpenWrt.org

. $IPKG_INSTROOT/lib/functions.sh
. $IPKG_INSTROOT/lib/functions/service.sh

initscript=$1
action=${2:-help}
shift 2

start() {
        return 0
}

stop() {
        return 0
}

reload() {
        return 1
}

restart() {
        trap '' TERM
        stop "$@"
        start "$@"
}

boot() {
        start "$@"
}

shutdown() {
        stop
}

disable() {
        name="$(basename "${initscript}")"
        rm -f "$IPKG_INSTROOT"/etc/rc.d/S??$name
        rm -f "$IPKG_INSTROOT"/etc/rc.d/K??$name
}

enable() {
        name="$(basename "${initscript}")"
        disable
        [ -n "$START" -o -n "$STOP" ] || {
                echo "/etc/init.d/$name does not have a START or STOP value"
                return 1
        }
        [ "$START" ] && ln -s "../init.d/$name" "$IPKG_INSTROOT/etc/rc.d/S${START}${name##S[0-9][0-9]}"
        [ "$STOP"  ] && ln -s "../init.d/$name" "$IPKG_INSTROOT/etc/rc.d/K${STOP}${name##K[0-9][0-9]}"
}

enabled() {
        name="$(basename "${initscript}")"
        [ -x "$IPKG_INSTROOT/etc/rc.d/S${START}${name##S[0-9][0-9]}" ]
}

depends() {
        return 0
}

help() {
        cat <<EOF
Syntax: $initscript [command]

Available commands:
        start   Start the service
        stop    Stop the service
        restart Restart the service
        reload  Reload configuration files (or restart if that fails)
        enable  Enable service autostart
        disable Disable service autostart
$EXTRA_HELP
EOF
}

. "$initscript"

ALL_COMMANDS="start stop reload restart boot shutdown enable disable enabled depends ${EXTRA_COMMANDS}"
list_contains ALL_COMMANDS "$action" || action=help
[ "$action" = "reload" ] && action='eval reload "$@" || restart "$@" && :'
$action "$@"
```

Hope some of you could shed light on this. Thank you!

PS:Another thing that i don't quite get is how the functions in the scripts are invoked by simply appending the function name to the full path of the startup scripts. for example, '/etc/init.d/vsftpd test' will execute a function named 'test' in either /etc/init.d/vsftpd or /etc/rc.common.But if 'test' function is defined both in the startup script and /etc/rc.common, the function in the former will be run while the one in rc.common will not.

Also, why is not

```
'[ "$action" = "reload" ] && action='eval reload "$@" || restart "$@" && :'
```

simply written as

```
'[ "$action" = "reload" ] && action='eval reload "$@" || restart "$@"'
```

Thank you!

Comment: Is your first sample the entire script?

Comment: yes, i've just randomly picked a simple one! all the startup scripts share the same beginning line #!/bin/sh /etc/rc.common

Comment: The "hash bang" at the beginning of the file may provide optional arguments to the interpreter. So generally you could have `#!/usr/bin/sh [options]`. But a script file isn't considered an "option" to the shell, and I haven't seen a case where a shell script is offered as an argument in this manner. I did a quick test case in `bash` and didn't observe useful behavior (i.e., `bash` ignored the optional script file name parameter). Your `rc.common` file exhibits a correct way to include another script (precede with a dot (`.`)).

Comment: I checked all of my `rc.d` scripts in Fedora and none of them used the mechanism you're showing. Which distro of Linux do you have?

Comment: it's Openwrt, a lightweight distribution for wireless router with 32RAM or more.

Answer (score 2):

From `execve(2)` on a fairly current Linux system:

> **Interpreter scripts**
>
> An interpreter script is a text file that has execute permission
>   enabled and whose first line is of the form:
>
> ```
> #! interpreter [optional-arg]
> ```
>
> The interpreter must be a valid pathname for an executable which is
>   not itself a script. If the filename argument of execve() specifies an
>   interpreter script, then interpreter will be invoked with the
>   following arguments:
>
> ```
> interpreter [optional-arg] filename arg...
> ```
>
> where arg... is the series of words pointed to by the argv argument of
>   `execve()`.
>
> For portable use, optional-arg should either be absent, or be
>   specified as a single word (i.e., it should not contain white space);
>   [...]

I have not seen many scripts in the wild using the `#!/bin/sh filename` idiom. I find its use confusing.

Perhaps a simple test will illustrate. These files should be present in /tmp/test, which matters in this case, given the details of the interpreter line in test_interpreter.sh.

The script named in the "#!" line (rc_interpreter_line) arranges to run commands in the originally invoked script, which I do via the sourcing_script variable and shift command. The code you quote in the question does a rather more complicated version of this chaining. Without this kind of chaining, all that runs is the file named in the interpreter line.

Contents of rc_interpreter_line

```
echo '===='
echo $0 "$@"

TESTVAR=set

sourcing_script=$1
shift

. "$sourcing_script" "$@"

echo '===='
```

Contents of test_interpreter.sh

```
#!/bin/sh /tmp/test/rc_interpreter_line

echo '-----'
echo "My file name is test_interpreter.sh, but \$0 is $0"

echo Command line: $0 "$@"

echo "TESTVAR is '$TESTVAR'"
echo '-----'

exit 0
```

Permissions:

```
sh-4.2$ ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 dev dev 104 Aug 24 13:36 rc_interpreter_line
-rwxr-xr-x 1 dev dev 191 Aug 24 13:36 test_interpreter.sh
```

Sample runs. Run test_interpreter.sh directly first.

```
sh-4.2$ ./test_interpreter.sh -opt arg1 arg2
====
/tmp/test/rc_interpreter_line ./test_interpreter.sh -opt arg1 arg2
-----
My file name is test_interpreter.sh, but $0 is /tmp/test/rc_interpreter_line
Command line: /tmp/test/rc_interpreter_line -opt arg1 arg2
TESTVAR is 'set'
-----
```

The second invokes the shell more plainly. No `execve(2)` behavior firing, so this run of the shell simply runs the commands in test_interpreter.sh, treating that first line as a comment.

```
sh-4.2$ sh test_interpreter.sh -opt arg1 arg2
-----
My file name is test_interpreter.sh, but $0 is test_interpreter.sh
Command line: test_interpreter.sh -opt arg1 arg2
TESTVAR is ''
-----
```

But my personal preference is to avoid the idiom entirely. It's far clearer to me to simply use commands early in scripts like:

```
. /etc/rc.common
```

...rather than rely on "interesting" '#!' lines, and in doing so create different behavior when using `./my_script` and `sh my_script`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply! but i still don't quite understand how the functions in the scripts are invoked by simply appending the function name to the full path of the startup scripts. for example, '/etc/init.d/vsftpd test' will execute a function named 'test' in either /etc/init.d/vsftpd or /etc/rc.common.Thanks again!